# How to access .json file in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I was given a json dataset `dataset.json`, which has the data:

```
[
     {
       "id": 1,
       "title": "Class 1",
       "videoUrl":
           "https://tech-assignments.yellowclass.com/1213_shipra_mam_7_papercrumpling_ice_cream/hls_session/session_video.m3u8",
       "coverPicture": "https://picsum.photos/800/450"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "title": "Class 2",
       "videoUrl":
           "https://tech-assignments.yellowclass.com/1215_shipra_mam_8_papercruumpling_birthday_cap_1/hls_session/session_video.m3u8",
       "coverPicture": "https://picsum.photos/800/450"
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "title": "Class 3",
       "videoUrl":
           "https://tech-assignments.yellowclass.com/1216_shipra_mam/hls_session/session_video.m3u8",
       "coverPicture": "https://picsum.photos/800/450"
     },
];
```

This is just a sample, actually it has 60 ids("id": 60). Now I need to access this data and how am I supposed to do that?

And if I want to access a particular data what should I do? for example: I want to access video url from this dataset, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the assets

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/dataset.json
```

Load it from the assets

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/dataset.json');
```

See [Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) for details.

Decode it

```
import 'dart:convert';

final dataset = jsonDecode(jsonString);
final firstVideoUrl = dataset.first['videoUrl'];
```

See [JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) for details.